Jupyter Notebook Variable Inspector not Working
I am currently using jupyter notebook to run my python code for my project and trying to monitor variables. I have installed the Nbextensions with Variable Inspector activated, however I cannot see any variable values in the Variable Inspector pop-up window and I saw an error message in the JS console of the webpage mentioned in some solutions I found in Google. The error message is as below,
your textkernel.js:1010 Couldn't process kernel message SyntaxError: "undefined" is not valid JSON
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at html_table (main.js?v=20240426151306:130:24)
at code_exec_callback (main.js?v=20240426151306:168:38)
at Kernel._handle_output_message (kernel.js:1199:1)
at i (jquery.min.js:2:1)
at Kernel._handle_iopub_message (kernel.js:1239:1)
at Kernel._finish_ws_message (kernel.js:1018:1)
at kernel.js:1009:1

Unlucky those solutions are for other issues and just mentioned this error by the way. I can see the extension button and pop-up window with nothing as the following figure,
Variable Inspector Pop-up window
Does anyone know how to handle this issue? I am kind of newbie to Jupyter Notebook, and any help will be highly appreciated!
I have no idea what is going on with this kernel error message and hopefully someone met this before and know how to resolve.

What version of Jupyter specifically are you trying to use? Jupyter Notebook 7+ doesn't use work with jupyter-contrib-nbextensions at all. It's a whole different system, like JupyterLab.

@Wayne Hi, thank you for your reply. According to my Anaconda navigator, my Jupyter Notebook version is 6.5.4 which I think is fine with Nbextensions.

Yes, 'Jupyter Notebook 6.5.0 Release Candidate' makes this clear. That rules out the new version being an issue. I was hoping some mixing was the root of your issue.
